# Distinct not working as expected in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm expecting the output of the below to have only one `qid` not two, because I'm using `->distinct('qid')`.

```
$update_18 = DB::table('posts') 
       ->distinct('qid')
       ->get();
```

Vardump shows two objects in the array, while I expected only one object with one `qid`:

```
array(2) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#340 (21) { ["id"]=> int(27) ["created_at"]=> string(19) "2019-10-18 18:15:20" ["updated_at"]=> string(19) "2019-10-18 18:15:20"  ["qid"]=> int(137) ["qrank"]=> int(1) } [1]=> object(stdClass)#341 (21) { ["id"]=> int(28) ["created_at"]=> string(19) "2019-10-18 18:15:47" ["updated_at"]=> string(19) "2019-10-18 18:15:47"  ["qid"]=> int(137) ["qrank"]=> int(1) } }
```

What am I missing ?

Comment: try using group by

Comment: `distinct` does not take any argument

Comment: @ascsoftw `distinct` doesn't have arguments defined but it does use arguments if they are there via `$columns = func_get_args();` though

Comment: @lagbox Thanks for the info, wasn't aware of it.

Comment: @ascsoftw though that might only be in 6.x, which potentially is not the version they are using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
$update_18 = DB::table('posts')
       ->groupBy('qid')
       ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `distinct` as below:

```
$query = DB::table('posts')->distinct()->get(['qid']);
```

Comment: But this will not return any fields except "qid"

Answer (score 0):

[distinct() method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#selects) in laravel does not take any params. So simply use like this :

```
$update_18 = DB::table('posts') 
             ->distinct()
             ->get();
```